# Codeigniter Login Issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm having difficulties in understanding what's going on here.

I've made a login page, setting it to go to admin page. Without any user data yet, just to check if it's working. And It doesn't go. I hade some problems loading the **library form_validation**. So I added the parent construct.

Controller

```
class Login Extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url'); 

}

public function index() {

    $this->load->view('login');
    $this->load->helper('url'); 

}

public function login() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|md5');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
        $this->index();
    }else{
        $user_session=array(
            'Username'      => $this->input->post('username'),
            'Password'      => $this->input->post('password'),
            'is_logged_in'  => 1
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_session);
        redirect('login/admin');
    }

}



public function admin() {
    $this->load->view('admin');

}

}
```

My Login View

```
 <section class="login_content">
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <form action="<?php echo base_url().'login/login'; ?>" method="post">
        <h1>Login no Sistema</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="separator">


          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <br />
          <div>
            <h1> Sitio Monica e Marcia</h1>

            <p>©2016 Todos os direitos reservados. Sitio Monica e Marcia.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- form -->
    </section>
```

My Admin View

```
 <div id="login" class="animate form">
    <section class="login_content">
        <h1>Bem vindo ao Admin</h1>
        <?php 
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
            echo '<pre>';

        ?>
      <!-- form -->
    </section>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you try `$this->admin();` instead of `redirect('login/admin')` ?

Comment: Ok, it is not redirecting to  redirect('login/admin');

Comment: Just did. Still the same....

Comment: Did you got any error message? Did you check apache error log?

Comment: Also please check the response from `$this->form_validation->run()` function

Comment: No error message, and my apache error log I have nothing today.

Comment: Are you getting a blank page? Or the login page itself?

Comment: can you please try to put " redirect('login/admin'); " on top of the function " login() " body.

Comment: RJ Anoop, The page itself.

Comment: Ranjeet Singh, If I put it on top, still stay on the same page.

Comment: So it might be an issue with the form validation. Please check the output of the form validation.

Comment: I've added a session on the login. and getting smth at the admin, but still not redirecting, I'll post my changes

Comment: And I'm getting this:

Array
(
    [session_id] => bcc26964ebd60a7422a1d83066761404
    [ip_address] => ::1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
    [last_activity] => 1459170310
    [user_data] => 
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here Is Your Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    /* Description: Login controller class*/
 class Login extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('session');
     $this->load->model('login_model');

}

public function admin($msg = NULL){
    // Load our view to be displayed
    // to the user
    $data['msg'] = $msg;
    if($msg == NULL)
    {

    $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else
    {
        //print_r($data);
    //die();
    $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }
}

 public function process(){
    // Load the model

    // Validate the user can login
    $result = $this->login_model->validate();
    // Now we verify the result
    if(! $result){
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
        $msg = 'Invalid username or password';
        $this->admin($msg);
    }else{
        // If user did validate, 
        // Send them to members area
        redirect('home/check_isvalidated');
    }        
}
public function doLogout(){

    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url());
   }
 }
```

Here IS The Model You Can Use Validation instead of Security

```
public function validate(){
    // grab user input
    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('user_name'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean(md5($this->input->post('password')));

    // Prep the query
    $this->db->where('user_name', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->db->get('admin');
    // Let's check if there are any results
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        // If there is a user, then create session data
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'user_name' => $row->user_name,
                'validated' => true
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    // If the previous process did not validate
    // then return false.
    else {
    return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

redirect(base_url('login/admin'));

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should check your link and session. This is the code

login.php in controller

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url'); 

}

public function index() {

    //$this->load->view('login');
    $this->load->view('login');

}

public function login() {

    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|md5');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
        $this->index();
    }else{
        $user_session=array(
            'Username'      => $this->input->post('username'),
            'Password'      => $this->input->post('password'),
            'is_logged_in'  => 1
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('userlogin',$user_session);
        $this->admin();
    }

}

public function admin() {
    $this->load->view('admin');

}
```

login.php in view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php echo 'http://localhost/answers/index.php/login/login'; ?>" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="username">Username:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And admin.php in views

```
<div class="container" height=100%>
  <h2>Welcome to the system, 
    <?php 
        $this->load->library('session');
        $login_session = $this->session->userdata('userlogin');
        //$username = $this->session->userdata('userlogin');
        echo $login_session['Username'];
    ?>
  </h2>
</div>
```

May you want to see the complete code like http://explicitphp.blogspot.co.id/2016/03/Codeigniter-Login-System-Tutorial-Without-Database-Connection.html

Hope answer your question. Have fun guys

Answer (score 0):

first, i don't know if the Login.php file or the class Login extends CI_Controller is a reserved name, try changing it.

then you have a public function called login(), this can have problems with the constructor, because in php5 or above you call the constructor like the class name and you maybe override the constructor